# Warning: newtype `CInt' is used in an FFI declaration,

Tags: haskell, ffi

When building gtk2hs-buildtools with ghc 7.4.2, I get the following warning:

```
c2hs/toplevel/C2HSConfig.hs:110:1:
    Warning: newtype `CInt' is used in an FFI declaration,
             but its constructor is not in scope.
             This will become an error in GHC 7.6.1.
    When checking declaration:
      foreign import ccall safe "static bitfield_direction" bitfield_direction
        :: CInt
```

I get similar warnings with FFI calls, even though I have `import Foreign.C.Types(CInt)`.

What is the correct way of getting rid of this warning?

Comment: The correct way to fix this is to pull from the gtk2hs darcs repository. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Foreign.C.Types(CInt(..))
```

to get the constructor.